# TypeScript: Abstract property missing type information in child class

Tags: typescript

I'm using TypeScript 3.4 and I have a weird problem with the following code

```js
interface MyInterface {
  fn: (x: number) => number;
}

abstract class A {
  abstract prop: MyInterface;
}

class B extends A {
  prop = { fn: x => x }; // complains about x having implicit any here
}
```

TypeScript complains about my function having an implicit any parameter. Now when I write class B like so

```js
class B extends A {
  prop: MyInterface = { fn: x => x }; // does not complain anymore!
}
```

the problem goes away and TypeScript understands that `x` is a number. Usually TypeScript knows that `prop` in my example is of type `MyInterface`, but for functions it does not work correctly.

Can anyone explain to me what I'm doing wrong? This is the minimal example to reproduce the issue. In my actual code I have all the things split into different files and have to import the corresponding `MyInterface` for every implementation of the abstract class while it should be inferred.

Comment: I was able to recreate the problem with your minimal code example. Have you checked Typescript documentation for an explanation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a [known design limitation of TypeScript](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667), which has been closed as "won't fix".  Your expectation is that the `class B extends A` would [contextually type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-inference.html#contextual-typing) property initializers of `B` to be constrained to the types of the corresponding properties of `A`, but this doesn't really happen.

There were [efforts to fix it](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/6118), but apparently it broke too much existing code to be worth it.  [@sandersn](https://github.com/sandersn) [said](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3667#issuecomment-217341966):

> Unfortunately, we couldn't come up with a solution that was both consistent and backward-compatible. The breaks in our Real World Code suite were more bad than good.

So it looks like you'll have to do the typing manually.  One way to avoid importing the property type name is to use a [lookup type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) like this:

```
class B extends A {
  prop: A['prop'] = { fn: x => x }
}
```

In that, the type `A['prop']` is resolved to be `MyInterface` for you.

Anyway, hope that helps.  Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for going into so much detail! Lookup type definitely eases the primary pain point for me :)